# Return the original value of the top 3 absolute values by row pandas?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I would like to return the top 3 values, after they've been sorted by their absolute values. SO a df like this

```
    0   1   2   3
0   2.822437    1.667583    -1.505558   -0.608644
1   0.357442    1.159013    -1.634652   2.270087
2   1.988308    1.129140    -0.725482   0.049260
```

Should return this

```
0   First   Second  Third
0   2.82243z    1.667583    -1.505558
1   1.159013    -1.634652   2.270087
2   1.988308    1.129140    -0.725482
```

How can this best be achieved? I need to sort them on the absolute value, but I need to return the original value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after; this uses numpy to do most of the work before rebuilding a dataframe :

```
array = df.to_numpy()
# gets the absolute value
# then gets the indices that would sort the array
# since just the top three is needed and the max
# we drop the first column and flip the rows
positions = np.argsort(np.abs(array), axis=1)[::-1, 1:]
new_array = np.take_along_axis(array, positions, axis=1)[:, ::-1]
new_array = pd.DataFrame(new_array, columns=["First", "Second", "Third"])
new_array

    First         Second    Third
0   2.822437    1.667583    -1.505558
1   2.270087    -1.634652   1.159013
2   1.988308    1.129140    -0.725482
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=abs)[1:][::-1],1).tolist())
Out[16]: 
          0         1         2
0  2.822437  1.667583 -1.505558
1  2.270087 -1.634652  1.159013
2  1.988308  1.129140 -0.725482
```